# :not(:placeholder-shown) gets always applied

Tags: html, css

I have this markup and css:

```css
.k-textbox {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  height: 35px;
  color: #3e5569;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #e9ecef;
  appearance: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
  font-family: "Nunito Sans", sans-serif;
}

.x-floating {
  position: relative;
}

.x-floating > .k-textbox {
  height: calc(3.5rem + 2px);
  padding: 1rem 0.75rem;
}

.x-floating-label {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.x-floating > .x-floating-label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1rem 0.75rem;
  pointer-events: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transition: opacity 0.1s ease-in-out, transform 0.1s ease-in-out;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.x-floating > .k-textbox.k-state-focused,
.x-floating > .k-textbox:not(:placeholder-shown) {
  padding-top: 1.625rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.625rem;
}

.x-floating > .k-textbox.k-state-focused ~ kendo-label,
.x-floating > .k-textbox:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ kendo-label {
  opacity: 0.65;
  transform: scale(0.85) translateY(-0.5rem) translateX(0.15rem);
}
```

```html
<div _ngcontent-wdo-c582="" class="x-floating">
  <kendo-textbox _ngcontent-wdo-c582="" placeholder="&nbsp;" ng-reflect-placeholder="&nbsp;" dir="ltr" class="k-textbox">
    <span class="k-input-prefix"></span>
    <input class="k-input" id="k-88ec96dd-1f83-4385-805d-7540a0d153f8" ng-reflect-events="[object Object]" tabindex="0" placeholder="&nbsp;" title="">
    <span class="k-input-suffix"></span>
  </kendo-textbox>
  <kendo-label _ngcontent-wdo-c582="" text="Username" class="x-floating-label" ng-reflect-text="Username" dir="ltr">
    <label class="k-label"> Username</label>
  </kendo-label>
</div>
```

The issue with it is, that the floating label is always in floated position, even if there is no input value entered (and of course it isn't focused). A dummy placeholder is set.

I think, something is wrong with this selections:

```
.x-floating > .k-textbox:not(:placeholder-shown)
.x-floating > .k-textbox:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ kendo-label
```

They are already on page load applied, which is wrong. I tried to target the `k-input` class element (although the `k-textbox` class element has the `placeholder` attribute too), but no success.

What is the missing key?

EDIT: the result looks messy, this is just a part of a bigger html, but illustrates the problem

Answer (score 0):

As noted in MDN:

> The :placeholder-shown CSS pseudo-class represents any `<input>` or
> `<textarea>` element that is currently displaying placeholder text.

`kendo-textbox` is not one of those so likely will always make `:not(:placeholder-shown)` true.

Perhaps you need to create an event that would add a class or attribute in `kendo-textbox` that reflects `kendo-textbox > input:placeholder-shown`, if that is even possible.

Comment: Well, that's true with the placeholder. I came up with this selector: `.x-floating > .k-textbox > .k-input:not(:placeholder-shown)`.  This works, but after that I should somehow target the `kendo-label` element. Which means, the first occurence after this selector. Or in an other way: target the parent back and then the sibling. Selecting the parent seems a very wish from developers. Is there any way to select the next element with a specified type regardless of it's level?

Comment: This might be what you need but it's still a draft: https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#has-pseudo

Comment: I didn't mention, that this is an angular project. So, at the end, I did this: `[ngClass]="{ floating: kendotextbox.value }"`. Now the class of the textbox element reflects the content of the input value.

Comment: That's no longer about `:placeholder-shown` but good for you.